# ✖ (U+2716) character displaying incorrectly in Chrome 97 on Windows 11

Tags: css, fonts, windows-11

I'm using the `✖` character ([HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X (U+2716)](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2716)) at several points in the template, but when I view the page using Chrome 97 on Windows 11 the character displays as below:

[image: It looks like a + symbol instead of a X.]

Poking around in Chrome DevTools it seems to be an issue with the [Segoe UI Emoji](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-ui-emoji) font which is supplied with Windows 11. Disabling this font fixes the issue, though obviously only locally. Viewing the page with Chrome on Android also displays the correct character.

I would like the character to display correctly for Windows 11 users. I could fiddle with the CSS on the page so it doesn't use Segoe UI Emoji, but I was wondering, am I missing something? Or is this a known issue with a fix? Or whether it's just a case of changing the font and waiting for Microsoft to fix it at some point in the future.

Comment: Relevant: [bug report on Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/windows/forum/all/windows-11-emojisegoe-ui-emoji-heavy/88df0c81-32f8-49fd-b3a4-8b43810028fe).

Answer (score 0):

Devices and applications organize emojis according to the emoji families they contain, so they present them to users in different views.
There is no definitive working solution to this.

You can use svg (vector) instead of using emoji.

I converted the emoji you specified to svg format, here are the codes:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="114.000000pt" height="121.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 114.000000 121.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,121.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M125 1020 l-60 -60 190 -190 190 -190 -190 -190 -190 -190 63 -62 62 -63 187 188 188 187 187 -187 188 -188 62 63 63 62 -190 190 -190 190 190 190 190 190 -63 62 -64 63 -182 -187 c-100 -104 -185 -188 -190 -188 -5 0 -90 83 -188 185 -99 102 -183 185 -187 185 -4 0 -33 -27 -66 -60z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

selecting the svg element; You can color the Svg however you want using css fill: color. Svgs are immutable and are the same on every device. animations are applicable and easy to use.

You can read SVG and CSS Blog:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_and_CSS

Answer (score 0):

The glyph for U+2716 is apparently just wrong in Windows 11; you can see it [if you click on "Microsoft" on Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/multiply/). They used an X for every version of Windows until Windows 11 November 2021 Update. This bug affects other apps too; Windows Terminal, among others.